# Unparseable date: when convert date from dd MMM yyyy format to dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: java, datetime

I get Unparseable error when I run below code. How can I convert dd MMM yyyy format to dd/MM/yyyy format?

```
public Calendar myMethod(){
   String dateStr = "16 Dec 2014"
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
   Date thedate = formatter.parse(dateStr);

   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime(thedate);
   return cal;
}
```

Comment: Where are the `"`s around `dd/MM/yyyy`? Is it a typo?

Comment: That code won't compile. Please provide a short but complete program which actually demonstrates the problem... there's no point in us looking at the code you've entered here, as it clearly isn't what you're actually running. Additionally, you're not doing any formatting here, contrary to your title. Finally, you've missed out a really important piece of information: your system locale.

Comment: And even if you add the quotes and such, how do you expect a parser configured for `dd/MM/yyyy` to parse `dd MMM yyyy`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you fix the blatant syntax errors, then:

```
String dateStr = "16 Dec 2014"                // <== This date is in dd MMM yyyy
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dd/MM/yyyy); // <== This SDF is in dd/MM/yyyy
Date thedate = formatter.parse(dateStr);      // <== So how can it be expected to parse?
```

What you do is create a parser for the format you need to parse, and a formatter for the format you want:

```
String dateStr = "16 Dec 2014";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
Date thedate = parser.parse(dateStr);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateStrReformatted = formatter.format(thedate);
```